# Set a timeout for flask_executor

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way to set a timeout for flask_executor threads or processes running in the background? Ideally, it would be something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_executor import Executor

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['EXECUTOR_TIMEOUT'] = 10
executor = Executor(app)
```

or

```py
@app.route('/run_fib')
def run_fib():
    future = executor.submit(fib, 5)
    future.set_timeout(10) # no delay here
    return 'OK'
```